# proftpd cannot upload (550 error)

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I have Proftpd installed on Ubuntu 9.04 server. FTP users are listed in auth file, e.g. these are not proper linux users, just FTP. They can connect and download files but when it comes to MKD or uploading, its always 550: Permission denied error. I've read quite a few tutorials on the net and still cannot get it working. I'm quite new to server administration... goes without saying.

proftpd.conf:

```
<Directory /path/to/relevant/dir>
 Umask 022 022
 AllowOverwrite                 on
       <Limit WRITE>
        AllowAll
      </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Relevant dirs are owned by the user proftpd runs as. They have writing permissions. I suppose you cannot just point directly to the cause and say "fix this", but if you could help me to debug it I'd most appreciate it. i.e. for starters I dont even know if it's purely proftpd configuration problem or can it be linux permissions problem or something else entirely? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of proftpd support forums, I figured this one.

UIDs and GUIDs in AuthUserFile must match one(s) of real Linux user(s) with the right ownership/permissions for the relevant FTP directories.