# ProFTPD. Can upload only in root directory, but it is failed when upload in subdirectories

Tags: centos6, proftpd

I can retrieve files but cannot edit and upload. However, I can upload files and directories to root directory.

Here I found a solution, but I have UIDs and GUIDs that match linux users.
[proftpd cannot upload (550 error)](https://serverfault.com/questions/103266/proftpd-cannot-upload-550-error)

Here the site which helped me to setup ProFTPD https://kyup.com/tutorials/install-configure-proftpd/

As /var/www/site.com/public_html belongs to apache user I changed user and group from nobody/nogroup to apache, but it doesn't solve problem.

```
ServerName          "ProFTPD server"
ServerIdent         on "FTP Server ready."
ServerAdmin         root@localhost
ServerType standalone
DefaultServer           off
AccessGrantMsg          "User %u logged in."
DeferWelcome            off
DefaultRoot         ~ !adm
AuthPAMConfig           proftpd
AuthOrder           mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c
IdentLookups            off
UseReverseDNS off
Port                21
#Umask              022
ListOptions         "-a"
AllowRetrieveRestart        on
AllowStoreRestart       on
MaxInstances 30
User                apache
Group               apache
UseSendfile         no
ScoreboardFile          /var/run/proftpd.score
<Global>
  AllowOverwrite        yes
  <Limit ALL SITE_CHMOD>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
RootLogin off
</Global>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x>
ServerName "vps.site.com"
LoginPasswordPrompt on
Port random_port
DefaultRoot ~
AuthOrder                       mod_auth_file.c mod_auth_unix.c
AuthUserFile /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
AuthGroupFile /etc/proftpd/ftpd.group

<Directory /var/www/site.com/public_html>
 Umask 022 022
 AllowOverwrite                 on
       <Limit WRITE>
        AllowAll
      </Limit>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

 cat /etc/passwd
support:x:501:501::/var/www/site.com/public_html:/sbin/nologin
cat /etc/group
support:x:501:

cat ftpd.passwd
support:xxxxxxx:501:501::/var/www/site.com/public_html:/sbin/nologin
cat ftpd.group
group_name:x:501:
support:x:501:
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems I can see so far.

1. In proftpd.conf, you have:

`User                apache`

`Group               apache`

These two lines you can safely remove.

2. The `umask` for virtual host:
   `umask 022`
3. The how to you are using, has configured valid shell (`/bin/bash`) for ftp user, but your user (support) don't.